# React add multiple components

Tags: reactjs

I'm kind of new to react and I have a basic ish question, but when browsing the web I couldn't find a solution that could help.

I have a component that is adding a user for a web application and a component inside of that called 'NewAnimal' that is a set of input boxes. When I click the button "Add Animal Entry", I want to be able to repeat the 'NewAnimal' component in case a user has multiple animals to register to an account. I tried to do this in the repeatComponet function but I'm unsure how (Ignore onAddAnimals as this is just me attempting to add the new animal to the create User state).

```
<div class="new-owner-div-2">
                    <h5>Owners Animals</h5>
                        <hr/>
                            <NewAnimal onAddAnimals={addNewAnimalHandler}> </NewAnimal>
                            <div>
                                <button className='addNewAnimal' onClick{repeatComponet}>
                                     <dt> Add Animal Entry</dt>
                                </button>
                            </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: store your state in an array - then use `.map`

Comment: This doesnt work, as i want to have it so when i click the button "Add Animal Entry" a new div is added regardless if the last one is filled in or not

Comment: Post your whole code, along with state